# Do skincare sheet masks fall in the liquids category for carry ons?

Tags: europe, airports, airport-security, hand-luggage

I will be travelling from Amsterdam to Barcelona with only a carry on.

As a makeup/skincare loving person, I have currently already packed the max of 10 liquids (with a max of 100ml). However, I would also like to bring a facial mask, preferably to use in the plane or the night we land. The facial masks I use are [sheet masks](http://www.charlottetilbury.com/nl/dry-sheet-face-mask.html?istCompanyId=dd29382f-a081-4392-851b-7e839ba1d9e2&istItemId=xptlmplixl&istBid=tztx&gclid=CMjp3YGurdsCFVeBhQodYbAA4g&gclsrc=ds&dclid=CM3d6IGurdsCFZHKdwodBNoDiA), which are kind of like wet wipes you put on your face for 15-20 minutes.

Now I now that wet wipes do not fall in the liquids category, but what about these face masks?

Some details:

- They are commercially packaged
- They are individually wrapped
- The sheet itself is moist
- The package will have some drops of excess liquid (cream or something alike) when you take the mask out.

I would prefer to find official rules on this. So far I can only find experiences of people in the US who said they just didn't present them to TSA as a liquid and were fine.

Comment: Can you tell where you got a max of 10 containers of liquid? All instructions I read it says 'all your containers of 100 ml or less have to go into one closable plastic bag of one liter and that has be be closed easily. If you happen to have containers of 5 ml, you might be able to fit 100 of them into that bag with space to spare.

Comment: @Willeke wow I think in my mind I just did the 1l/100ml math and figured okay, 10. Thanks!

Comment: @Willeke European limits are different to the USA.  See https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/carry/luggage-restrictions/index_en.htm

Comment: @PeterM, I agree that the USA and Europe have different sets of rules, they are just about identical. In the USA the sizes are quoted in oz and quart, in Europe in ml and liter, but the actual rules are very much alike, almost to the ml. (Have you read that site you linked to?) I have traveled from Europe to the USA and back and in both cases nobody counted any of the containers in any of the plastic bags. I do not know whether there are other rules world wide, but where I have seen differences is was 'no liquids', never a number of containers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the site [Your Europe - Luggage Restrictions](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/carry/luggage-restrictions/index_en.htm) which says in part

> Liquids carried in the aircraft cabin such as aerosols, drinks, toothpaste, cosmetic creams or gels must be carried in a transparent plastic bag - maximum capacity 1 litre - and no container may hold more than 100 ml. Liquid containers larger than 100 ml must be placed in checked baggage. The volume restriction does not apply to medicines and baby food.

So that covers  the cosmetics side of things.

This has a link to [Information for air travellers](https://ec.europa.eu/transport/modes/air/security/info_travellers_en) (buried under `See the rules on prohibited articles in your hand and hold luggage.`

Under the section `Preparing your luggage` is a link [List of prohibited articles in your hand luggage.](https://ec.europa.eu/transport/sites/transport/files/modes/air/security/doc/info_travellers_hand_luggage.pdf) which takes to a PDF that lists all of the usual bad things you can't take in hand luggage.

But nowhere in all of this is anything about the masks you want to carry, and as you are aware they don't seem to fit into the any of the previously mentioned categories.  My best guess is that you will be fine as they are really akin to facial wipes and there is no need to present them for inspection.

My second guess is that you should be prepared for them to be confiscated from your hand luggage and only take the bare minimum with you on the plane.  If they are not confiscated then you win!

You don't mention if you will have checked luggage, but if you do, that is where I would place the bulk of your masks.

Comment: No checked luggage for this trip sadly. I will get myself a cheap version of the mask in case I have to throw it away. Thanks!

Comment: If in doubt and if they fit, put them in with the liquids, or ask at the security checkpoint and offer to put them in with the liquids. (+1 for writing it in a proper answer, with links and all.)